# How can I append an item to a list in js in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I created a Parent Component js file and changed the state fo numbers list by adding 10 to it but it is showing error as there is no push funtion.Could anyone help me with this??

```
import React, { Component,PureComponent } from 'react'
import Reg from './Regularcomp'
import Pure from './PureComp'

export class Parentcomp extends PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         name:"Mayank",
         numbers:[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
}


componentDidMount()
{
    setInterval(()=>{
            this.state.numbers = this.state.numbers.push(10)
    },1000)
}

render() {
    console.log("*****Parent Component*******")
    return (
        <div>
            Parent is Pure Component
            <Reg name={this.state.name}/>
            <Pure name={this.state.name}/>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Parentcomp
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please **strongly** consider adding more context to your ❓ besides just code. Currently you code formatting is off and there is nothing else provided.

Answer (score 0):

[`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) interface in react class components is a complex structure. It doesn't provide you any plain `setters` on your data structrue. The only setter you may use on it is [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method. So you should rewrite your `componentDidMount` as:

```ts
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            numbers: [...prevState.numbers, 10]
        }));
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Your code is saying Cannot read property push of undefined

Comment: Why push function of array is not applicable here ? I couldn't find any reason for it

Comment: React detects when the object changed by comparing _references_. And push operation doens't change the reference of the `numbers` array. And while the object will change inside, react will not trigger rerender because the reference didn't change.

Comment: Is this because I used PureComponent Class as Parent Class.What if I use only Component class as my parent class then it should always re-render .It is not working either.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case. It _may_ accidentally help if the parent component constantly rerenders the _child_ component. But it's definitely won't be rerenders synced with child state updates.